# Changing Background Images per state

Tags: apache-flex, coding-style, states

I have a Component that has a specific background image. The code looks like:

```
<mx:backgroundImage>@Embed(source='img1.png')</mx:backgroundImage>

<mx:states>
  <mx:State name='state2'>
    <mx:SetStyle name="backgroundImage">
      <mx:value>@Embed(source='img2.png')</mx:value>
    </mx:SetStyle>
  </mx:State>
</mx:states>
```

But when I change the state to `'state2'`, it doesn't actually change anything.

Am I missing anything specific here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this seems to be kind of a weird error, my temporary solution is to have two canvases with different backgrounds that flip visibility depending on the state

Answer (score 1):

The default target is the main app.
So you are actually setting the background of the entire app in state2 and not the Component.
Here is an example with the *VBox*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:states>
    <mx:State name="state2">
        <mx:SetStyle name="backgroundImage" target="{VBox1}">
            <mx:value>
                @Embed(source='img2.jpg')
            </mx:value>
        </mx:SetStyle>
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>
<mx:VBox id="VBox1" x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%">
    <mx:backgroundImage>
        @Embed(source='img1.jpg')
    </mx:backgroundImage>
</mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

Also if you are using Flex 3 Builder you can always switch to Design mode to see changes from Base state to a new state. It should be in the top right corner.

**EDIT for components**

**Main file**

```
<cbsh:BackSwitch>

</cbsh:BackSwitch>

</mx:Application>
```

**Component**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="400" height="300">
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="state2">
        <mx:SetStyle name="backgroundImage" target="{this}">
            <mx:value>
                @Embed(source='img2.jpg')
            </mx:value>
        </mx:SetStyle>
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>
<mx:backgroundImage>
        @Embed(source='img1.jpg')
    </mx:backgroundImage>
<mx:Button x="437" y="269" label="Switch!" click="currentState='state2';"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

Comment: I actually was doing all of this through design mode, but it didn't add a target. I tried adding `target="{this}"` which now looks fine in design mode, but doesn't seem to actually work when I compile

Comment: Well I updated the example for components and it works so you will have to say how your component is based (Vbox,Canvas etc) and how your state changes, I used click.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dealt with this specifically, but my intuition is that it is having a problem with the way the value is set. 
Have you tried this:

> mx:setStyle setStyle name="backgroundImage value="@Embed(source='img2.png')" />

Comment: appears to have given me the exact same result - strange